# Отправка капчи в форму сайта python с использованием requests

Tags: python, requests

Только изучаю питон, не могу понять, что делаю не так. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
captcha = None
url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/?page=" + str(k) + "&keywords=" + req
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
captcha = soup.find(text="Robot Check")
while captcha != None:
    cap = open('cap.html','w')
    cap.write(str(soup))
    cap.close()
    capin = input("Требуется ввод Captcha. Введите Captcha из файла cap.html: ")
    s = requests.Session()
    data = {"captchacharacters" : capin}
    r = s.post(url, data=data)
    s.cookies
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    captcha = soup.find(text="Robot Check")
```

Собственно, сохраняю файл html, если амазон требует ввод капчи. Остаётся отправить ему капчу, но я, видимо, делаю что -то не так, ибо амазон снова бесконечно запрашивает капчу.

Comment: ну, одной страницей дело вряд ли получится закончить -- еще есть заголовки http (Request Headers) и куки (Cookie)

Comment: Советую открыть инструменты разработчика в браузере и посмотреть в сетях какие запросы ходят при появлении капчи и при отправки ее значения

Comment: `captcha` намекает, что это не для потребления ботов интерфейс. У amazon много много существующих API. Попробуйте его вызвать вместо попытки обойти меры защиты.